# flourishlib throws exception when trying to store an empty string as a value of a not-null column

Tags: php, mysql, flourishlib

I have a class `Question` inherited from `fActiveRecord`.

When I try to run the following code:

```
$question = new Question();
$question->setQuestion($_question)->setUseruid($useruid)->setOriginuid($originuid)->setStatus(0)->setAnonymous($anonymous)->store();
```

the system throws an exception (I am sharing only the message, not the stack trace):

```
Answer: Please enter a value
```

Now, I have tried to give a value to that answer field, as follows:

```
$question = new Question();
$question->setQuestion($_question)->setUseruid($useruid)->setOriginuid($originuid)->setStatus(0)->setAnonymous($anonymous)->store();
```

but I have no luck, I get the same error.

answer is a `not null` `longtext` field in the mysql database table `questions`. It is able to hold the '' value, but it seems impossible to store empty string as the value of a `not-null` field using flourishlib. Is this a bug or am I missing something? Is there a work-around?

Answer (score 0):

Flourish converts empty string to null, which is a BUG in my opinion and a really big one. This BUG made me unable to insert a new record using flourish into the given table and I had to use alternative means to achieve my goal. This should be fixed ASAP in my opinion. The picture below illustrates my claim.

[image: flourish documentation]